# Orientation of WPF status bar and label are in wrong place when the window is maximised

Tags: wpf, orientation, statusbar

In my serial port WPF application , the labels (BaudRate,Parity,DataBits and stopBit) and the StatusBar (for displaying PortStatus) are in wrong place when I maximise the window.

I would like to have suggestion from expertise to resolve my issue.

So please let me know if I can make any changes/edit on my xaml file to have these orientation on the same place as it is in Normal window mode.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SerialReadAndWrite"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="ATR220ReadAndWrite.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ATR220ReadAndWrite" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-71,-107">
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComPortComboBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="115,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" SelectionChanged="ComPort_SelectionChanged" DropDownOpened="ComPort_DropDownOpened" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Label Content="PortNumber :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="PortSettings :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.546,3.143" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="359,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.23,0.36"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="BaudRateComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Height="17" SelectionChanged="BaudRate_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>115200</System:String>
            <System:String>57600</System:String>
            <System:String>38400</System:String>
            <System:String>19200</System:String>
            <System:String>14400</System:String>
            <System:String>9600</System:String>
            <System:String>4800</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ParityComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="308,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" SelectionChanged="Parity_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>Even</System:String>
            <System:String>Mark</System:String>
            <System:String>None</System:String>
            <System:String>Odd</System:String>
            <System:String>Space</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="DataBitsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="115,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" SelectionChanged="DataBits_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" FontSize="8" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>5</System:String>
            <System:String>6</System:String>
            <System:String>7</System:String>
            <System:String>8</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="StopBitsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="308,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" SelectionChanged="StopBits_SelectionChanged" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>One</System:String>
            <System:String>Two</System:String>
            <System:String>OnePointFive</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Baudrate :" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="47,81,753,423" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" Width="63"/>
        <Label Content="Parity :" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="234,81,573,423" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" Width="56"/>
        <Label Content="DataBits :" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="48,123,753,382" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" Width="62"/>
        <Label Content="StopBit :" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="238,123,567,382" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic" Width="58"/>
        <Button x:Name="ConnectButton" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ConnectButton_Click" IsEnabled="False" Height="14" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Label Content="ProtocolCustomWndow :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.546,3.143" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ProtocolTypeComboBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="141,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" SelectionChanged="ProtocolTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial" IsEnabled="False">
            <System:String>WLink</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        ***<StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="0,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794">
            <StatusBarItem FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed">
                <TextBlock Name= "PortStatus"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>***
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Images of the correct and wrong pics are attached.

wrong position
[Wrong Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYMR.png)

Correct position
[Correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b4oe.png)

Comment: Stop using Margins!!!, use column definitions and row definitions for your Grid.

Comment: I am new to WPF , so please kindly let me know how to use them on my xaml file?

Comment: I have updated my answer, also you should update your post instead of posting code that you tried as an answer.

Comment: 1. delete your answer as you should update your question. 2. I need more information about your second question, you're better of asking another question and I will be happy to answer it, but remember to put more information in there.

Comment: I have added another question as per your request but I do not know how to share with you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="PortNumber :" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">COM 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Connect" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"></Button>
    <TextBlock Text="PortSettings :" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Baudrate :" FontStyle="Italic" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <System:String>115200</System:String>
        <System:String>57600</System:String>
        <System:String>38400</System:String>
        <System:String>19200</System:String>
        <System:String>14400</System:String>
        <System:String>9600</System:String>
        <System:String>4800</System:String>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Parity :" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Pay special attention to use of `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`, you will need to set the Horizontal Alignment on these elements but this will show you how to position things in `WPF`.